# block a website with google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, xcode, google-chrome-extension, blocking

there is manifest code and background.js, I was trying to make it like this, I can't find solution for this problem, I found a code which is getting url and, code which can block sites, i mixed them and get like this
manifest code:

```
{
"name": "Loki",
"manifest_version": 2,


"description": "ეს არის ქართული სატესტო უსაფრთხო ნეტ სერფინგისათვის შექმნილი გაფართოება",
"version": "0.1",
"permissions": \["webrequest", "webrequestBlocking", "\<all_urls\>","tabs"\],
"background": {

"scripts": \["background.js"\]
},
"icons": {
"16": "icons/logo_16x16.png",
"48": "icons/logo_48x48.png",
"128": "icons/logo_128x128.png"
}
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
  let url = tabs[0].url;
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function (details) {
      return { cancel: true };
    },
    { urls: url },
    ["blocking"]
  );
});
```